# Reverse method for map function (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list with the different values: `l = [0, 1, None, 2, False, 1, 0]`; after I used `list(map(str, l))` I got that: `['0', '1', 'None', '2', 'False', '1', '0']`. How can I return to initial list? I would not have problems with one-data-type list, but here is multiple one.

Comment: You would need many ifs

Comment: [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) in conjunction with a for-loop should be able to do it.

Comment: This is impossible in general. Consider for example, the string 'None' or 'False' occurring the original list - how could you distinguish? (Assuming we allow strings in the original list as well).

Comment: @costaparas I agree, that would be impossible to establish. If the first map-command used `repr` instead of `str` however, that would not be an issue.

Comment: @hampus using `repr` is a good workaround, at least in simple cases since it retains information that the `str` conversion loses. It gets a bit more complicated with custom objects, particularly if there is no trivial definition of `__repr__` for such objects -- and recovery in that case would require use of `eval` rather than `ast.literal_eval`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) the same way

```
from ast import literal_eval

l = [0, 1, None, 2, False, 1, 0, 1.5]

res = list(map(str, l))
print(res)  # ['0', '1', 'None', '2', 'False', '1', '0', '1.5']

res = list(map(literal_eval, res))
print(res)  # [0, 1, None, 2, False, 1, 0, 1.5]
```